# Dynamically Expand Subgrid in a loop - JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, subgrid

I have Grid with a subgrid using subGridRowExpanded.

And I want to dynamically expand some rows of the grid so I wrote following 
in GridComplete Event of First Grid.
ids is array of row ids of my Grid

```
for(int i =0; i< ids.length; i++) {
    //Checking with condition
    $("#myGridName").expandSubGridRow(ids[i]);
}
```

I also tried with following code, But for some reason checkboxes in GridComplete of second level, is added only for last expanded row.

```
$("#myGridName").expandSubGridRow(ids[0]);
$("#myGridName").expandSubGridRow(ids[1]);
```

Above code expands appropriate rows. But,

In GridComplete event of Subgrid, I've check boxes in each row.

So, Here I need to check some of the Chekc boxes.

But the Problem is,

The subgrid_row_id is getting wrong

i.e. ID of last subgrid to be expanded is assigned in SubGridRowExpanded of Parent Grid.

Note : I manually adding checkboxes to each row in subgrid

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean under "ID of last subgrid to be expanded is assigned in SubGridRowExpanded of Parent Grid". The problem with checkboxes are also unclear. Moreover it is important to know more information about the grid and subgrids which you use. For example: do you load data from the server or fill grid with local data? Which datatype you use for grid and subgrids?

Comment: In Grid as well as Subgrid, I'm using JSON data and filling both grids from Server. Instead of a running in a loop, I tried expanding only two rows of grid i.e. $("#myGridName").expandSubGridRow(ids[0]); and $("#myGridName").expandSubGridRow(ids[1]);... Then Here Two rows are expanded but, Checkboxes are only in last expanded grid.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you have very close problem as discussed in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459900/jqgrid-subgrid-doesnt-populate-with-data/6467539#6467539). What you try to do seems the same what [expandOnLoad: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid#properties) property of the `subGridOptions` option should do. Like I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459900/jqgrid-subgrid-doesnt-populate-with-data/6467539#6467539) jqGrid don't support queuing of Ajax requests. If you execute

```
$("#myGridName").expandSubGridRow(ids[0]);
```

with remote `datatype` or `subgridtype` ('json' or 'xml') the Ajax request will be sent to the server. Till we receive the corresponding response from the server the internal property

```
$("#myGridName")[0].grid.hDiv.loading
```

will be set to `true` and all other Ajax requests for example from `$("#myGridName").expandSubGridRow(ids[1])` will be just **skipped (ignored)**.

The same problem (bug) exist in the current implementation of `expandOnLoad: true`. If you open in [the official jqGrid demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) the "Hierarchy (4.0) new" tree node and then look at the demo "Expand all Rows on load" you will see that *not all rows are correctly expanded* as promised (you have to scroll the grid to see all subgrids).

I think that to implement expanding of subgrids on load correctly you should do about the following

- You should examine the list of collapsed subgrids (the corresponding row has class "sgcollapsed") and **expand only the first found subgrid**.
- The expanding of the next subgrid should be done **only after the response from the server will be received and processed**.

I can recommend you to use `success` callback function of `ajaxSubgridOptions` jqGrid options because there are no `loadComplete` event after loading the subgrid. The current implementation of the Ajax request in subgrid uses `complete` callback function of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.subgrid.js#L162)) which will be called *before* `success` callback. So you can define your `success` callback as the method of the  `ajaxSubgridOptions` option of jqGrid. Inside of the `success` callback you can call `$("#myGridName").expandSubGridRow(ids[i])` for the next node (if any still not expanded). In the way you can open all subgrids.

To enumerate subgrids more effectively [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080859/jqgrid-iterate-over-the-grid-data-in-a-subgrid/7084920#7084920) could be helpful for you.

Comment: @stacktrace: You are welcome! I hope, that I understood correct the problem which you have.